# Mapping a generated database column to a Grails domain class property

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In my Grails 2.5.X app, I have a domain class that looks like this:

```
class FormData {

    String submittedFields
    Boolean submitted

    static constraints = {
        submittedFields nullable: true
    }

    static mapping = {        
        // can I do something here to map submitted to a generated
        // column of the form_data table
    }
}
```

I would like to map the `submitted` property to a generated column of the `form_data` table, i.e. a column that would be created by the SQL statement

```
alter table form_data add submitted tinyint 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (if(submitted_fields is null,0,1));
```

Specifically, this generated column should be created when I create the schema from the domain model, e.g. by running the `schema-export` script.

A consequence of `submitted` being mapped to a generated column is that the corresponding domain class property should be read-only, or at least, assigning a value to it should have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle the value of the column on database side only, and dont want it to be inserted or updated from grails/hibernate side. you can make the column as insertable:false updatetable:false

```
static mapping = {
 submitted insertable:false, updateable:false
}
```

Now, even if the value is changed in grails, the new value will not be updated in database.

Comment: thanks for your reply, it's very help, but doesn't answer the other part of my question: how do I get grails to include this column in the generated schema?

Comment: Do you mean the database migration plugin ? -- that should generate the column without any issues

Comment: I mean when Grails generates the schema, e.g. when the `schema-export` script is run, or when the application is started in `dbCreate = "create-drop"` mode. As things currently stand, there's no way Grails can create this column, because I haven't defined the nature of it anywhere in the domain model, by "nature", I mean `submitted tinyint 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (if(submitted_fields is null,0,1))`